# RecyclerView listener gets called on its own

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I am setting a listener to my `RecyclerView checkbox`. When the `checkbox` is clicked it should mark the item as favorite in the DB. But the listener gets called on its own even without clicking.

Here's the `Recyclerview`

```
    class KafanaAdapter(private val kafani: List<Kafana>, private val listener: OnItemClickListener) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<KafanaAdapter.KafanaViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): KafanaViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binder = ItemKafanaBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
        return KafanaViewHolder(binder, listener)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: KafanaViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(kafani[holder.adapterPosition])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return kafani.size
    }

    class KafanaViewHolder constructor(private val binder: ItemKafanaBinding, private val listener: OnItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binder.root) {

        fun bind(kafana: Kafana) {
            binder.kafana = kafana
            binder.tvKafanaTitle.text = kafana.name
            binder.tvKafanaAddress.text = kafana.address
            binder.ivCall.setOnClickListener { listener.onKafanaClicked(kafana) }
            binder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                kafana.isFavorite = isChecked
                listener.onKafanaFavoriteClicked(kafana)
            }
        }
    }

    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onKafanaClicked(kafana: Kafana)
        fun onKafanaFavoriteClicked(kafana: Kafana)
    }
}
```

And here's the part of my `Fragment` where the interface is implemented:

```
override fun onKafanaFavoriteClicked(kafana: Kafana) {
    doAsync {
        if (kafana.isFavorite) mViewModel.setFavorite(kafana, 0) else mViewModel.setFavorite(kafana, 1)
        uiThread {
            toast("Favorite")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you study the source code of the `CompoundButton` widget (which is the `Checkbox`'s superclass), you'll find out there is a method called `setChecked(boolean)` which calls the provided `CheckedChangeListener`.

Now, the `setChecked()` is called by the `CompoundButton` itself at different times - when the widget's instance state is restored, inside the `onInitializeAccessibilityEventInternal()` method, in `CompoundButton`'s constructor, etc.

So, that's why the listener is called even if you didn't tap the checkbox.

Which options do you have?

1. Use `OnClickListener` instead and check whether the checkbox is checked or not inside `onClick()` method.
2. Use `CheckedChangedListener` and call the `checkbox.isPressed()` method inside the `onCheckedChanged()` method to find out whether it was user-initiated change or not.
3. Write your own version of the `Checkbox` class (probably based on the one in Android SDK) which does not call this listener unless it's sure the change occurred after the user clicked the checkbox.